# How can I find subdomains of splunk.com using http reponse?

Tags: curl, http, html

I have sent http request to the "splunk.com" with usin that command

```
curl -L splunk.com
```

I got html codes. I want to find subdomains of that website by parsing the html codes.

[image: Some part of html code]

Comment: Please remove your previous duplicate question, cause this one is detailed better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complex parsing/scaping with **xmlstarlet**, **xmllint** and **sed** tools:

```
curl -sL "http://splunk.com" | xmlstarlet fo --html --recover 2>/dev/null \
| xmllint --html --xpath "//a[contains(@href, '.splunk.com') and not(contains(@href, '//www.'))]/@href" - 2>/dev/null \
| tr ' ' '\n' | sed -E 's~^href="https?:[/]+~~; s/\.com.*$/.com/' | sort -u
```

The output:

```
answers.splunk.com
conf.splunk.com
dev.splunk.com
docs.splunk.com
investors.splunk.com
live.splunk.com
login.splunk.com
splunkbase.splunk.com
splunklive.splunk.com
usergroups.splunk.com
```